# Android SQLite Syntax Error - get more information

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm setting a up a SQLite DB in Android using SQLiteOpenHelper...
When I execute the program LogCat logs an error when the onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) method is called:

> near "Table": syntax error

This is my SQL statement:

```
db.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE +  " (" + 
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +       
                KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_REPS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_WEIGHT + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

As I declared all the variables such DATABASE_TABLE, this should work.
Is there a way to see what's actually going wrong or is my SQL just buggy?!

Any help is appreciated!

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";   -> this could be buggy
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
public static final String KEY_REPS = "Reps";
public static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "Weight";   

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Workout";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Table";
```

Comment: What is the value of `DATABASE_TABLE`?

Comment: Can you show the values of your constants? Your syntax is fine, so perhaps you are using reserved words for the column or table names.

Comment: Also, I believe that a column declared `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will autoincrement without the `autoincrement` keyword

Comment: Do you have the logcat output you can post?

Comment: Post your Keys to What are they, you may be using something that you shouldnt be for column names.

Comment: sorry this is the only output: near "Table": syntax error

Comment: Get rid of the space before the first `(`

Comment: OK this solved the problem, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess: try the following:

```
db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE '" + DATABASE_TABLE +  "' ('" + 
            KEY_ID + "' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '" +       
            KEY_DESCRIPTION + "' TEXT NOT NULL, '" +
            KEY_REPS + "' TEXT NOT NULL, '" +
            KEY_WEIGHT + "' TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

This surrounds all identifiers with single quotes. If any of these labels contain special characters or reserved words, that should do the trick.

Comment: i think you are right with special characters -> public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

Comment: this is no necessary for `_Id` this is fine in column name declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to create your SQL as a string.  You can then display the SQL via Log.i(...

I'd really need to see the values of your variables, first guess is it doesn't like your table name.
But from what I can see with what you have, it looks correct.

My Sample `private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
                + MOVES_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

                + KEY_GAME_ID + " INTEGER, " 
                + KEY_LANGUAGE_PREF + " INTEGER, "
                + KEY_BOARD + " TEXT, " 
                + KEY_POSITION + " TEXT);"`

Comment: will this speed up the process?

Comment: No, but it will allow you to get the actual string used in the application and put it into a tool like sqlitestudio or sqlite data browser and check if you are getting the result the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I use a helper method to do the logging

```
static void logSql (SQLiteDatabase db, String sql, Object... bindArgs) {
    if (Sanity.verboseLog) {
        Log.i (TAG, sql);
    }
    db.execSQL (sql, bindArgs);
}
```

And everywhere I access the database I check this Sanity (a la Stroustrup) variable

```
public static class Sanity {
    public static final boolean checked = false;

    public static final boolean waitForDebugger = checked;
    public static final boolean forceStartupSync = checked;
    public static final boolean writeDbToSd = checked;
    public static final boolean showDebugActions = checked;
    public static final boolean debugLog = checked;
    public static final boolean verboseLog = checked;
    public static final boolean debugContentProvider = debugLog;
```